# Best way to calculate the paycheck

Tags: vb.net

I want to calculate my paycheck taking in consideration few paramethers like holidays/ sundays/saturday etc which are paid more than the business day.
I'm trying to follow a simple logic.

The rules to follow are

1. business day - from 06am to 10 pm paid normally hourly wage
2. night - from 10 pm to 06 am paid normally hourly wage plus a 4$ added on the total. (p.s. I am eligible for the 4$ added on the total only if I work at least 3 hours at night)
3. saturday - each hour get paid 30% more
4. sunday - each hour get paid 0.70$ more
5. holiday - each hour get paid 35% more if I work max 7 hours - 40% from the 8th hour and forth

It can happen that I work on saturday night until sunday morning so I need to get a right calculation. Also It can happen to work on a sunday holiday with get paid 35 ( or 40%) plus 0.70$ each hour. This wouldn't happen in case I work on an holiday on saturday, cause the biggest % absorb the smaller % so on holiday in saturday I only get paid 35( or 40% based on how many hours..)

I'm trying with Few numericUpDown ( 5 in total  - business day, night, saturday, sunday, holidays) controls and two textboxes. First textbox contains the normal hourly wage ex 10%. The second textbox contains the total amount of the paid day.

The code I wrote so far is

```
   Dim filledalready As Boolean
   Private Sub nighthours_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles nighthours.ValueChanged
       If filledalready = False Then
           If night.Value >= 3 Then
               total.Text = CStr(CDbl(night.Value) * ((CStr(CDbl(hourlywage.Text) + CDbl(hourlywage.Text) * 30 / 100))))
               filledalready = True
           End If
       Else
           total.Text = CStr(CDbl(total.Text) + CStr(CDbl(night.Value) * ((CStr(CDbl(hourlywage.Text) + CDbl(hourlywage.Text) * 30 / 100)))))
           filledalready = True
       End If

   End Sub

   Private Sub dayhours_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dayhours.ValueChanged

       If filledalready = False Then
           total.Text = CDbl(day.Value) * CStr(CDbl(hourlywage.Text))
           filledalready = True
       Else
           total.Text = CStr(CDbl(total.Text) + CDbl(day.Value) * CStr(CDbl(hourlywage.Text)))
           filledalready = False
       End If

   End Sub
```

I've tried using a boolean variable because if I set the worked hours for a business day and then add few hours from the night, it would make errors on the calculation, but also It still doesn't get what I want and still it would give wrong numbers as output.
I'm wondering if I'm following the right way to do it and if not, please feel free to point me out to the right path.

Comment: You've done a great job listing out the requirements, but you've probably need to explain in a little bit more detail exactly what part of this solution isn't working and how it's not meeting your requirements.  As it stands right now your question sits somewhere between a logic flow question and debugging.  If your issue is around logic, you're probably a bit early in the process to be posting here.  If help with debugging, you need to update your question with the debugging details so far.

Comment: One other question for you, you're counting days and working out the pay, can it happen someone starts working at say 8pm and works to 3am, is the 2 hours paid at the standard rate, then 5hrs at the overtime rate, and what happens if it's 8pm on a Saturday, and finish at 3am on a Sunday which is also a public holiday?

Comment: Hi Hursey, thanks for replying. The issue is about debugging. The code I wrote only works in the case the total textbox is empty. I'll explain this with your first example. From 8 pm to 3am, I add 2 hours on the day numericUpDown control ( total is now 20$) and I add 3 night hours ( total should be now 20 + (10x3)+30%)) but my code doesn't care about the 20$ already sitting in there.  The issue stands after each Else, but I don't know how to make it work.. I thought I could fix it with a boolean variable, but still don't get what I want.

Comment: To answer to your second question, I'm not considering sunday as a public holiday, endeed that's paid as a simple hourly wage + 0.71$ per hour.  So I add 2 saturday hours 10$ x 2 + 30%, plus 5x 10.71$

Comment: Ahh, so you need a form level decimal variable to hold the accumulated total, then display that value in total.Text.

Comment: Also I was meaning, "What if" the Sunday is a weekend.  Poorly worded question on my part.

Comment: Do you mean if sunday is a holiday? well, in that case we can say that you get paid 10.71 + 35% or 35% What If I work on a holiday day which is sunday at night? well, 10.71  + 35% or 35% + 4$ on top of the total

Comment: let's say that If I can find a way to solve my issue without changing too much the my code would be great so I can meke it in until the end. But obviously, any kind of better way to do it would be great for me to improve my code.

Comment: Well, I would say a form level variable would be a fairly simple change.  You might also want to consider a readonly property that does the calculation, then you could even go as far as to implement data bindings and INotify (A lot bigger can of worms) to your controls which will save you all that CStr <-> CInt backwards and forwards your doing

Comment: Would you mind to make me an example of the code you are thinking about? 
let's say I m quite scared now to open a bigger can of worms and for this exactly little personal utility, I wouldn't mind using all that cstr and cdbl eventhough that's quite horrible to look at. The readonly variable wouldn't be that far from my understanding, but I'm quite curious about how you would manage this kind of problem. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to be completely honest, this is very off the top of my head and more focused on the how rather than implementing your rules and logic but hope this might serve as a starter for you.  There are a lot more elegant solutions that this as well.

```
Public Class Form1

Const StdRate = 17.45
Property StandardHours As Integer
Property OvertimeHours As Integer
Property WeekendHours As Integer
Property PublicHolidayHours As Integer

ReadOnly Property TotalPay As Double
    Get
        Return (StandardHours * StdRate) + (OvertimeHours * (StdRate + 4)) +
            (WeekendHours * (StdRate * 1.7)) + (PublicHolidayHours * (StdRate + (StdRate * 0.35)))
    End Get
End Property


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    txtStdHours.DataBindings.Add("Value", Me, "StandardHours", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
    txtOvertimeHrs.DataBindings.Add("Value", Me, "OvertimeHours", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
    txtWeekendHrs.DataBindings.Add("Value", Me, "WeekendHours", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
    txtPublichHolidayHours.DataBindings.Add("Value", Me, "PublicHolidayHours", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
    txtTotal.DataBindings.Add("Text", Me, "TotalPay", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
End Sub
End Class
```

Also note I've used a Constant for the standard pay rate, you might have another textbox or something around that holds that.  You can apply the same principles to it by adding it's own property and bindings etc

Comment: Hi Hursey Many thanks for your answer. 
I'm quite afraid that this answer goes really above my vb.net skills since I never used DataBinding.. I'm taking the opportunity to read a bit now about it and it seems about to store things inside a database. Correct me If I'm wrong.
I meant to create a simple personal tool without using a database, I thought more of a really simple numericUpDown control like I've tried to do, but obviously without any kind of error about calculation. The logical path i was following might not seem the best but it was the easiest to me to keep going with it

Comment: Do you think there is a way to fix what I was trying to do without change too much my code?
However, I'm going to mark your answer as the best to whoever will need.. But in my case, i need a noob answer ahah.. Thanks

Comment: DataBindings while yes, very helpful in connecting to databases, they are more about connecting UI to a Data Model.  Data Models are really just a object for a specific purpose I guess is one way to explain it.  Regarding Fixing your original code, goes way back to what I said in one of the original comments.  Form level variable to hold the total pay while you calculate it but would 100% suggest you do some reading on data bindings etc because in the long run it's handy

Comment: Or maybe just drop a button on the form, in the click event do all the calculations in one hit

Comment: Ive tried already the button still have the same issue.. its not realizing that there is already a value in the variable or in the textbox and it will sum up a bigger number than the real one.... :/